# Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA "Cannot undo. Unexpected document state"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Why does Android Studio give me this message sometimes when I try to undo?:

Cannot undo. 
Unexpected document state

[image]

Comment: It is broken, report a bug.

Comment: oh my god i just lost 10 hours of work

Comment: Try to use local history to revert.

Comment: It's been broken in IntelliJ forever!!! How hard can it be to have it fixed! Silly error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old bug reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156074).

I've just had the same error in 2023: my uncommitted changes just disappeared in the file for no reason (after running an npm build) and I could not undo it.

As @Steven commented, local history helped:

Go to `file -> local history -> show history` and pick the latest.

Congrats, your 10h of work are saved!